# making rest requests without using HttpClient or DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, rest, socket.io

I am trying to develop a **Java** client side program that makes REST requests to the server. I want my program to open only one connection (using one port) and make all requests from that connection. When the last request is finished then the connection will be closed. I want to use web socket etc. to make the connection from server to client. *In addition, I want to make the requests **without** using HttpClient or DefaultHttpClient.*

Is that possible? If possible, how can I do it?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: How do you think `HttpClient` connects to the server?

Comment: I think that, when DefaultHttpClient calls execute method HttpGet object inside it(as parameter), it connects the server. Thus it can get response from that server. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try XMPP ... It sends XML stanzas as http:// posts so technically not that different, but creates persistent connections that stay alive ... and operates on a different port, which might be a problem if ur behind a fire wall ... unless BOSH

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. But I must use **REST** protocol with JSON body.